# extension UIAlertController convenience init warning

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, warnings, uialertcontroller

When I define a `UIAlertController` convenience initializer:

```
extension UIAlertController {
    convenience init(message: String?) {
        self.init(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    }
}
```

and use it in a button action in my subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
func buttonAction(button: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(dictionary: nil, error: nil, handler: nil)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and click that button on the Simulator, I get a warning:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (UIAlertController)

However, I don't get a warning if instead of a convenience initializer, I use a global function:

```
func UIAlertControllerWithDictionary(message: String?) -> UIAlertController {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    return alert
}
```

I've reported this to Apple as an iOS SDK bug.

Until it's fixed, is it OK to ignore the warning and use the convenience initializer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I noticed the same issue with convenience initializers.
It's actually two bugs at once.

1. Swift allocates a `UIAlertController` instance.
2. Swift calls your convenience init with the instance created by Swift.
3. There you call UIKit's convenience init, which is actually the Objective-C factory method `+(id) alertControllerWithTitle:message:preferredStyle:`.
4. There UIKit allocates its own `UIAlertController` instance. **(Bug #1)**
5. UIKit sets up its own instance.
6. UIKit deallocates your Swift instance.
7. `UIAlertController`'s `deinit` (dealloc) accesses the `view` property which leads to the log message. **(Bug #2)**
8. Control comes back to your own convenience init where `self` silently changed from Swift's `UIAlertController` instance to the one from UIKit.
9. Everything you do now happens on the instance created by UIKit which is fine.

So the first bug is that Swift creates a temporary `UIAlertController` which is destroyed without ever being used.

The second bug is that `UIViewController` accesses the `view` property during deinitialization which it shouldn't.

---

Regarding your question:
Both bugs shouldn't be problematic so we can simply ignore the warning for now. I do that too and there weren't any problems yet - just that warning in the log.

Comment: Wow. Excellent debugging skills! How do you know all this? Did you just use the Xcode debugger, set a breakpoint, and step through?

Comment: A mix of experience, knowledge of the Objective-C runtime and yes, debugging :)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (UIAlertController)

So I moved to the alternate way for this.

```
 import UIKit
import Foundation

//the show alert function for failure
func showAlertforNetworkFailure(alerttitle :String, alertmessage: String,ButtonTitle: String, viewController: UIViewController)
{


    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alerttitle, message: alertmessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okButtonOnAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: ButtonTitle, style: .Default)
        { (action) -> Void in
            //what happens when "ok" is pressed

    }
    alertController.addAction(okButtonOnAlertAction)
    alertController.show()



}

// function for show alert in Main View Controller
extension UIAlertController {

    func show() {
        present(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func present(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        if let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            presentFromController(rootVC, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }

    private func presentFromController(controller: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        if let navVC = controller as? UINavigationController,
            let visibleVC = navVC.visibleViewController {
                presentFromController(visibleVC, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }  else {
                controller.presentViewController(self, animated: animated, completion: completion);
        }
    }
}
```

call this method in your ViewController as

```
showAlertforNetworkFailure("Server Error!!!", alertmessage: "Server does not responding,please Try in later.", ButtonTitle: "Okay", viewController: self)
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Thank you. :-) I prefer my convenience initializer since it's less code and exposes the `completion` handler.

Comment: You should be able to simply call presentViewController without having to worry if it is the top view controller or not, from the documentation of UIViewController: The object on which you call this method may not always be the one that handles the presentation. Each presentation style has different rules governing its behavior. For example, a full-screen presentation must be made by a view controller..... If the current view controller is unable to fulfill a request, it forwards the request up the view controller hierarchy to its nearest parent